# How to calculate without button

Tags: javascript

How do I display value without any button?

```js
function multiplyBy() {
  var selPay = document.getElementById("pay");
  var pay = selPay.value;
  if (pay == 0) {
    num1 = 6;
    num2 = document.getElementById("callback").value;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 * num2;
  }
  if (pay == 1) {
    num1 = 12;
    num2 = document.getElementById("callback").value;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 * num2;
  }
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet, please add the HTML to create a [mcve] - try onkeyup

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to wrap all your code inside a Listener attched to element "pay",
assume your html input is like as below:
HTML :

```
> `<input type="text" id="pay" value="" />`
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
/* event listener */
document.getElementsById("pay").addEventListener('change', doThing);

/* function */
function doThing(){
   //doSomething now
}
```

in JQUERY (before 1.7):

```
$('#pay').bind('input', function() { 
    // do something with this now.
    $(this).val() // get the current value of the input field.
})
```

in JQUERY (1.7 onward):

```
  $('#pay').on('input', function() { 
      // do something with this now.
        $(this).val() // get the current value of the input field.
    });
```

or only listen to keyup event

```
 $('#pay').keyup(function() {
    // do something with this now.
        $(this).val() // get the current value of the input field.
    });
```

or using onkeyup event

```
<input type="text" id="pay" onkeyup="callYourFunc()">
```

using listener or bind you can update DOM real time ***without button***

Answer (score 0):

You may use [onkeyup](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) attribute for that.

```
<input type="text" id="result" onkeyup="multiplyBy()">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most complete version assuming a select, a text field and a span

I show plain JavaScript since that is what was tagged

```js
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("pay").onchange=
  document.getElementById("callback").oninput=
    function() { // onchange of select or modification of input
      var pay = document.getElementById("pay").value,
      callback= document.getElementById("callback").value,
          num1=0;
    switch(pay) { // this could be an array instead
      case "0": num1=6; break;
      case "1": num1=12; break;
    }
    var total = 0;
    callback=(callback == "" || isNaN(callback))?0:parseInt(callback);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 * callback;
  }
}
```

```html
Pay: <select id="pay">
<option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="0">Zero</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="callback" />: <span id="result"></span>
```

I chose oninput over document.getElementById("callback").onkeyup since it handles pasting too